# git p4 clone command gives error : failure accessing depot: could not connect

Tags: git, perforce

I am not able to run the **git p4 clone //depot/xyz** command on my git bash. It gives me error **failure accessing depot: could not connect** and just creates a empty directory with .git folder. 
I have done all the required configurations for git p4.

```
git-p4.py file is present at git/bin & git-core directories.
```

I set the p4 configurations like below in git bash

```
p4 set P4PORT=ssl:perforce1.xyx.net:1212
p4 set P4USER=<<user.name>>
p4 set P4PASSWD=<<password>>
```

However, if I enter **p4 client** command and edit the configuration giving the exact depot path like below, I am able to run **p4 sync** to load the project. So it doesn't look like a network/credentials/firewall/port etc etc issue: (below p4 client configuration lets me run p4 sync successfully)

```
  Client:   WKSWXXXXX

Update: 2018/10/03 04:21:40

Access: 2018/10/03 04:21:53

Owner:  neeraj.chand

Host:   WKSWXXXXX

Description:
    Created by neeraj.chand.

Root:   c:\Users\312846\git_test

Options:    noallwrite noclobber nocompress unlocked nomodtime normdir

SubmitOptions:  submitunchanged

LineEnd:    local

View:
    //depot/xyz/... //WKSWXXXX/...
```

I can confirm that **git p4** is successfully installed.
What could be going wrong here? Is it something related to git-p4.py ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it turns out, git p4 doesn't work properly with python 3.0.xx which I was using.
Changed to python 2.7.1 and everything works smoothly without doing any manual configuration (p4 client).

Just do the below configuration for p4 and you are good to use **git p4 clone //depot**

```
p4 set P4PORT=ssl:perforce1.xyx.net:1212
p4 set P4USER=<<user.name>>
p4 set P4PASSWD=<<password>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget

```
p4 login
```

first. You still need it even after setting the appropriate variables.

It is NOT mentioned here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-p4

Answer (score 1):

git-p4 has never worked with python3. I've been having a go at making it work - you can see my current attempt here:

https://github.com/luked99/git/tree/git-p4-python3-final-showdown

It still needs quite a bit of work, but a few of the tests are starting to pass. Most still fail though.